# Python add-in works once only?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-addin

There is a sample in ArcGIS 10.1 help on creating a add-in using python. This works only once when a layer is selected in combobox, if i need to use this functionality again it does not work and i need to restart arcmap again, then it works.

```
# Business logic to implement the ComboBox
def __init__(self):
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True

def onSelChange(self, selection):

    # When a new layer is selected, create a new fishnet using the extent of layer.
    layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd, selection)[0]
    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer.dataSource)
    extent = desc.Extent
    fishnet = arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(r'in_memory\fishnet',
                    '%f %f' %(extent.XMin, extent.YMin),
                    '%f %f' %(extent.XMin, extent.YMax),
                    0, 0, 10, 10,
                    '%f %f' %(extent.XMax, extent.YMax),
                    'NO_LABELS',
                    '%f %f %f %f' %(extent.XMin, extent.YMin, extent.XMax, extent.YMax), 'POLYGON')
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

def onFocus(self, focused):

  # When the combo box has focus, update the combo box with the list of layer names.
    if focused:
        self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd)
        self.items = []
        for layer in layers:
            self.items.append(layer.name)
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "doesn't work"? It works as expected for me. The fishnet layer remains in the TOC and is updated each time I select another layer in the drop-down list. Check under Geoprocesing > Geoprocessing Options that Overwrite the output of geoprocessing operations is enabled. This will let you overwrite the in_memory layer. A way to verify this causes any trouble is to delete the layer in the TOC and see if it will get re-created.

Comment: Hi Thanks, after changing geoprocessing options, it is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fishnet layer will remain in the TOC and will be updated each time you select another layer in the drop-down list.

However, check under Geoprocesing > Geoprocessing Options that `Overwrite the output of geoprocessing operations` is enabled. This will let you overwrite the in_memory layer. A way to verify this causes any trouble is to delete the layer in the TOC and see if it will get re-created.